# Mapping timeseries+static information into an ML model (XGBoost)

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, xgboost, feature-extraction

So lets say I have multiple probs, where one prob has two input DataFrames:

Input:

1. One constant stream of data (e.g. from a sensor) Second step: Multiple streams from multiple sensors

```
> df_prob1_stream1
         timestamp          | ident  | measure1     | measure2 | total_amount | 
----------------------------+--------+--------------+----------+--------------+
 2019-09-16 20:00:10.053174 | A      |        0.380 |     0.08 |      2952618 |
 2019-09-16 20:00:00.080592 | A      |        0.300 |     0.11 |      2982228 |
... (1 million more rows - until a pre-defined ts) ...
```

2. One static DataFrame of information, mapped to an unique identifier called `ident`, which needs to be assigned to the `ident` column in each `df_probX_streamX` in order to let the system recognize, that this data is related.

```
> df_global
 ident  | some1        | some2    | some3        | 
--------+--------------+----------+--------------+
 A      |        LARGE |     8137 |            1 |
 B      |        SMALL |     1234 |            2 |
```

Output:

1. A binary classifier `[0,1]`

So how can I suitable train `XGBoost` to be able to make the best usage of one `timeseries` DataFrame in combination with one `static` DataFrame (containg additional context information) in one prob? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you concatenate a window from a target position i (ie. a window size of 3 [i-3,i-2,...,i+2,i+3, static frame]?

Comment: @jhso: The binary classifier can be defined as `targets=[0,1,0,1,0]`. The probs can be defined as a multi-dimensional space, where one prob is the highest level, than every probe has two dimensions: The timeseries data and the static data. For every probe one `target` exists to be learned towards to.